# A band pass filter simulation in PSpice

Tags: filter, spice, orcad

I designed a Constant K (I don't remember the constant K) LC band Pass filter with lower cut off frequency 1 KHz and upper 5 KHz. Using the value of K, I deduced the values of L and C and made the following circuit:

[image: Schematic]

*I've used R1 = 999999G to show infinite resistance.*

I carried out the AC sweep (frequency response) in PSpice and got something like this:

[image]

Is the graph correct?

Also one more thing I want to ask is that, can we get Vout (output voltage, the green probe in the circuit diagram) more than 5V i.e. the input voltage?

Comment: Looks like it's unterminated. What characteristic impedance was it designed for? You need that impedance in series with the source, and the load (R1) should be that impedance.

Comment: What is your basic question?

Comment: R1 in the diagram just represents resistance of an oscilloscope which is ideally infinite. Characteristic impedance is 600 Ohms.

Comment: That is not true. Your typical 10x probe would be better modeled by 11M, in parallel with a ~10pF.

Comment: Alright mat. I'll try that and let you know if there are some changes. I didn't know this. Thanks for correcting.

Comment: After replacing R1 with a 10M andin parallel with 1-pF, I'm getting 3 peaks.

Comment: You still need to terminate it like Brian Drummound said earlier.